# Redistribute Visio Diagram so Begin & End are in the extremes

Tags: vba, visio

I created a VBA macro that creates a Excel spreadsheet-based diagram in Visio. However, when I try to re-distribute the layout of the diagram, somehow the "End" label always ends up in the middle of the drawing, instead of being linear from "Start" to "End". This is the only problem: all connectors are OK, all shapes contain the required information.

Is there a way to have Visio ensure both Start & End are left in the corners of the diagram? I was thinking there might be a property in the "Start" & "End" that could drive this behavior.

Edit #1: Added what I have of code, although is not really fancy.
As of now, the only thing I'm using to distribute the diagram is the standard option:

```
Sub vsDiagramClosure()
    'Layout Arrange
    With vsPag
        With .PageSheet
            .CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle).FormulaForceU = "1"
            .CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLORouteStyle).FormulaForceU = "5"
        End With
        .Layout
    End With
End Sub
```

I adapted that from the macro recorder. `vsPag` was declared as `Global vsPag As Visio.Page` & it already has been assigned the proper page.

Thanks,

Comment: Show us your code.
Also read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: What operation did you record in a macro to get that code?